# How to remove listview item from another class

Tags: c#, xamarin, tizen

For my Tizen .net Wearable app I want to be able to delete a listview Item when the check icon is pressed / toggled. The problem is however that the check element is in the CustomClass and the listview is in the AppClass.

I've tried making the check element global, but unfortunately without success.

```
namespace TizenWearableApp5
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            CirclePage circlePage = new CirclePage();
            CircleListView listView = new CircleListView();
            listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomCell));
            listView.ItemsSource = getTasks.Taken;
            listView.HasUnevenRows = true;
            MainPage = circlePage;
            circlePage.Content = listView;
            CustomCell.check.Toggled += (s, e) =>
            {

            };
        }
    }

    public class Taken
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Team { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomCell : ViewCell
    {
        public static Check check = new Check();
        public ObservableCollection<TaskViewModel> Taken { get; set; }
        public CustomCell()
        {
            Taken = new ObservableCollection<TaskViewModel>();
            StackLayout cell = new StackLayout()
            {
                HeightRequest = 120,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                WidthRequest = 360,
            };
            StackLayout left = new StackLayout()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            };
            Label name = new Label()
            {
                FontSize = 8,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            };

            Label team = new Label()
            {
                FontSize = 5,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            };
            check.DisplayStyle = CheckDisplayStyle.Default;
            check.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
            check.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;

            //Set Binding
            name.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
            team.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Team"));
            View = cell;
            cell.Children.Add(left);
            left.Children.Add(name);
            left.Children.Add(team);
            cell.Children.Add(check);
        }
    }

    public static class getTasks
    {
        public static IList<Taken> Taken { get; set; }

        static getTasks()
        {
            Taken = new ObservableCollection<Taken>() {
                new Taken
                {
                    Name = "Martin",
                    Team = "Red"
                },
                new Taken
                {
                    Name = "John",
                    Team = "Blue"
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to delete an item from the check event

Comment: have `CustomCell` raise an event when an item is checked, and then have your page subscribe to that event.

Answer (score 2):

You can access to Items source of ListView with `getTasks.Taken` because it is a static

and you can get item from BindingContext of instantiated customcell

So, now you can remove a item from Items source with `Remove` method of IList

Here is solution, please replace CustomCell with below code

```
    public class CustomCell : ViewCell
    {
        public ObservableCollection<TaskViewModel> Taken { get; set; }
        public CustomCell()
        {
            Taken = new ObservableCollection<TaskViewModel>();
            StackLayout cell = new StackLayout()
            {
                HeightRequest = 120,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                WidthRequest = 360,
            };
            StackLayout left = new StackLayout()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            };
            Label name = new Label()
            {
                FontSize = 8,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            };

            Label team = new Label()
            {
                FontSize = 5,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            };
            Check check = new Check();
            check.DisplayStyle = CheckDisplayStyle.Default;
            check.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
            check.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;

            check.Toggled += (s, e) =>
            {
                getTasks.Taken.Remove((s as Check).BindingContext as Taken);
            };

            //Set Binding
            name.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
            team.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Team"));
            View = cell;
            cell.Children.Add(left);
            left.Children.Add(name);
            left.Children.Add(team);
            cell.Children.Add(check);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could  custom an event into `CustomCell` like this ：

```
public class CustomCell : ViewCell
    {
        public event EventHandler OnToggled;
        public CustomCell()
        {

            Check check = new Check();
            ...
            check.Toggled += Check_Toggled;
        }

        private void Check_Toggled(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnToggled?.Invoke(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

then you could handle the event of `CustomCell`:

```
 CustomCell.OnToggled += (s, e) =>
        {

        };
```